# How to extract 2-word fields from Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
{   
"features": [{      
    "properties": {
        "lat": "1.2345",
        "location c": "aaa",
        "location q": "cccc"
    }
    }
 ]
}
```

So I can fetch `properties` and what next?

As you see above mentioned fields have 2 words.

```
 var location_c =  properties.get(/*???*/);
```

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 8):

Use bracket syntax.

```
 var location_c = properties['location c'];
```